# Java pdf to Excel Conversion

Tags: java, apache-poi, pdf-reader

I'm extracting data from PDF to excel. In that PDF contains table also. I used `Itext- pdf` to covert PDF to text & with the help of `apache poi` covert text to excel. but I'm not able to retrieve the data to store in the database. I tried `PDF-BOX`, `ASPOSE` also Same result I'm getting. If any one knows, Please help me to solve this issue.

Here is my code

// pdf to text using itext

```
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(
                    "C:\\Users\\mohmeds\\Desktop\\BOI_SCFS banking.pdf_page_1.pdf");
            PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(
                    reader);
            // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
            TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
            String line = null;
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                strategy = parser.processContent(i,
                        new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
                line = strategy.getResultantText();
            }
            reader.close();

            // using apache poi text to excel converter

            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
            System.out.println("link------->" + line);
            List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new StringReader(line));

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                String str[] = lines.get(i).split(",");
                Row row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
                for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
                    row.createCell(j).setCellValue(
                            helper.createRichTextString(str[j]));

                }
            }

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
                    "C:\\Users\\mohmeds\\Desktop\\someName1.xls");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
```

Comment: i think you should not close the reader

Comment: after closing reader also same result.

Comment: i mean you should close the reader after closing fileOut.close(); this one

Comment: What does the following mean? "but I am not able to retrieve the data to store in the database" What is the role of the database?

Comment: @sumit  Ya i did same result is coming

Comment: @ mm759 once i am getting the correct excel format then i will store the table contents to my database.

Comment: can you add  stack trace in your question

Comment: I am not getting any Exception. pdf to excel conversion is happens after conversion data is not in proper format.(scattered)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, but if you are looking to store data from the PDF into a database, it's likely you'll want to extract the data as CSV rather than Excel. Also, the code here eliminates the middle step of converting PDF to Text, then Text to Excel. When defining the format, choose 'csv':

```
package com.pdftables.examples;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class ConvertToFile {
    private static List<String> formats = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "csv", "xml", "xlsx-single", "xlsx-multiple" });

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Command line: <API_KEY> <FORMAT> <PDF filename>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        final String apiKey = args[0];
        final String format = args[1].toLowerCase();
        final String pdfFilename = args[2];

        if (!formats.contains(format)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid output format: \"" + format + "\"");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Avoid cookie warning with default cookie configuration
        RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build();

        File inputFile = new File(pdfFilename);

        if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("Can't read input PDF file: \"" + pdfFilename + "\"");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig).build()) {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://pdftables.com/api?format=" + format + "&key=" + apiKey);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(inputFile);

            HttpEntity requestBody = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("f", fileBody).build();
            httppost.setEntity(requestBody);

            System.out.println("Sending request");

            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost)) {
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    final String outputFilename = getOutputFilename(pdfFilename, format.replaceFirst("-.*$", ""));
                    System.out.println("Writing output to " + outputFilename);

                    final File outputFile = new File(outputFilename);
                    FileUtils.copyToFile(resEntity.getContent(), outputFile);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: file missing from response");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getOutputFilename(String pdfFilename, String suffix) {
        if (pdfFilename.length() >= 5 && pdfFilename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            return pdfFilename.substring(0, pdfFilename.length() - 4) + "." + suffix;
        } else {
            return pdfFilename + "." + suffix;
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/pdftables/java-pdftables-api/blob/master/pdftables.java